# Spring Boot + JWT returns "Access is denied"

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I have seen couple of this questions but without of solution.

I get the access token but when I try to hit the endpoint it gives me back "Access is denied".

I debugged the code and I can clearly see that I get all the right info for user and that he has right role.

WebSecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtProvider {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtProvider.class);
    
    @Value("${rs.test.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;
    @Value("${rs.test.jwtExpiration}")
    private int jwtExpiration;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

        UserPrinciple userPrincipal = (UserPrinciple) authentication.getPrincipal();
        
        return Jwts.builder()
                        .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                        .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                        .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpiration))
                        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                        .compact();
    }
    
    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                            .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
                            .parseClaimsJws(token)
                            .getBody().getSubject();
    }
    
    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature -> Message: {} ", e);
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Expired JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Unsupported JWT token -> Message: {}", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty -> Message: {}", e);
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

```
public class JwtAuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider tokenProvider;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthTokenFilter.class);
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                    HttpServletResponse response, 
                                    FilterChain filterChain) 
                                            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        try {
            String jwt = getJwt(request);
            if (jwt!=null && tokenProvider.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = tokenProvider.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(username);
                
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication 
                        = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can NOT set user authentication -> Message: {}", e);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    
    private String getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return authHeader.replace("Bearer ","");
        }
        
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthEntryPoint.class);
    
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException e) 
                                 throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        logger.error("Unauthorized error. Message - {}", e.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error -> Unauthorized");
    }
    
}
```

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder encoder;
    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    @Autowired
    private UserAssembler userAssembler;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> 
                        new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with -> email : " + username)
        );

        return UserPrinciple.build(user);
    }
    
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto) {
        
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginDto.getEmail(),
                        loginDto.getPassword()
                )
        );
        
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = jwtProvider.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt));
        
    }
    
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody UserDto dto) {

        if(userRepository.existsByEmail(dto.getEmail())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Fail -> Email is already in use!",
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // Creating user's account
        User user = userAssembler.assembleUserFromUserDto(dto, encoder.encode(dto.getPassword()), roleRepository.getOne(1L));
        
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("User registered successfully!");
    }
    
}
```

And endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class TestRest {

    @GetMapping("/api/test/user")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String userAccess() {
        return ">>> User Contents!";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/api/test/admin")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public String adminAccess() {
        return ">>> Admin Contents";
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not in config classes like I thought at first.
I named my roles USER and ADMIN but by documentation, spring security demand to have ROLE word before role name, so it looks like ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN.
So I changed role names in database and in enum and that fixed the problem:
USER -> ROLE_USER
ADMIN -> ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: The framework should not dictate your data. There are several solutions. The shortest one is to use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole` (role are but authorities with the ROLE_ prefix). Another one is to implement GrantedAuthority and override the getAuthority method, and then populate authorities into your JWT token and userdetails.

Comment: You're right that it shouldn't dictate my data and I really don't like it mostly because it seems very stupid to me. Thank you on advice for "hasAuthority" ! @MarcTarin